# guideline cruiscontrol.net in vs.net 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cruisecontrol.net

i am trying to install cruisecontrol.net together with vs.net 2010+ win 7 64 bit.

Does anyone have a link with a step by step explanation?

Comment: You should accept more of the answers you receive. People would be more inclined to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about that a little while ago. Hope it helps.
http://enterpriseyness.com/2010/04/setting-up-cruise-control-net-1-5-on-iis7/